# SQL Server-Execute dynamic boolean string as WHERE condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, boolean, dynamic-sql

I have a Boolean expression stored as a string in one of my tables and want to make that the condition for which that record is shown.

table:
Answer_CFG = [answer_Id], [Quest_ID], [condition]

ex:

'(SELECT findAns(1,1) as AnsID) <> 4' is stored in the 'condition' column

(findAns(a,b) is a udf I made that returns an int)

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @cond nvarchar(MAX)


SELECT @sqlCommand= 'SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND (SELECT Condition from Answer_CFG as ans2 WHERE ans2.answer_ID=ans1=Answer_ID)' 

SET @sqlCommand = REPLACE(@sqlCommand, '@QuestionID', @QuestionID)


EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Right now it wont even executing the udf that I have stored within there but even then, I tried executing that statement by itself and it would do the udf but would throw an error when trying to compare ('<>', '<=' etc....)

Let me know if this is even possible. I wanted to try something clever but it may just be a ditched effort at this point.

This is tied to  asp.net/C# for purpose of conditional drop down menus. I'd rather not have to hardcode a bunch of if statements.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to pull `[condition]` value to some `@variable` and then construct your @sqlCommand by adding it, like

```
select @sqlCommand='select ...whatever you want... where '+@variable
```

And you must know for 100% that no one will add condition like `1=1 drop table students` ;)

*Also you don't need to use REPLACE, it's better to use sp_executesql which can pass parameters to the query:

```
exec sp_executesql @sqlCommand,'@QuestionID int', @QuestionID
```

Comment: thanks. Yea i'm not allowing anyone to set the conditions lol. I wanted to split them up into separate parts (seemed like the more logical way), but I couldn't/still cant think of a way to find the condition for each row of the main select statement.

Comment: Do you need to apply conditions for all rows at once? In this case you need to use a cursor for questionIDs and a loop, I think. But it will not be fast, and if you have 10Ks of rows and need to run it really often you could get performance problems.

Comment: lol it probably wont ever have more than like 20 rows. Its a drop down list with possible answers for a specific question. So when the dropdown list gets filled, the condition checks the answers to a given question (getAns function) and either enables/disables the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the final query composing the fixed part with the condition stored in the table. The problem in your code is that it just SELECTs right from the table, not composing any statement. It's entirely possible to do what you want (even though it's widely considered a **bad practice**). You need to do it in 2 steps, first retrieving the condition, then merging it in the final query:

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @cond NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @Id INT = 1 ;   --Replace with the actual ID you want

--Get the condition string from table
SELECT @cond = Condition FROM Answer_CFG WHERE answer_ID=@Id ;

--Build the final query by concatenating the initial, fixed part with the condition extracted
SET @SqlCommand = 'SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND ' + @cond ;

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand,'@QuestionID INT', @QuestionID ;
```

**EDIT**

It seems that there is an additional problem, that it requires for each row to get a different condition, so the approach I wrote is not that easy. Problem is that we can't use the very same query, but a different one is needed for *each row*. This is the code that finally should get executed:

```
SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND 1=1;
SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND answ_id=38;
SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND something>otherthing;
```

The final condition is always different. Assuming this is OK and I've got the question well, try this:

```
DECLARE @SqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' ;

--Compose a SQL query for each row
SELECT @SqlCommand = @SqlCommand + 'SELECT Answer_ID FROM Answer_CFG as ans1 WHERE ans1.Quest_ID=@QuestionID AND ' + Condition + ';' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)FROM Answer_CFG ;

--See what actually gets executed
PRINT @sqlcommand ;

--Execute the multitude of SELECTs all at once
EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCommand,N'@QuestionID INT', @QuestionID ;
```

Problem with this is that it issues one query for each row in the table, leading to one result set per row queried. That's easy to fix by adding an UNION ALL inside the query string it generates, depending on your needs.

Comment: How could I have that ID joined with the AnswerID so that it does it for every row?

Comment: hmmm, I think I got what your doing, but then you're saying to loop through, execute, and join the generated sql statements?  what is the char(13), char(10) referring to? And sorry if I didnt make this clear, but the condition statement comes right from the same table/record as the answer_ID. In theory, I thought I could do something like..... 'select answer_Id, @cond=Condition FROM Answer_CFG WHERE Quest_ID=@questionID AND @cond'

Comment: No, no loops are necessary, the first `SELECT` does generate ALL instructions all at once and put in the @SqlCommand variable (put a `PRINT @SqlCommand` to see what it does), and the runs all at once again. The char 13 and 10 are just formating for easier debugging, but don't do anything vital really. The query you though is not hard with dynamic SQL, but the trouble comes from the fact that @cond is not fixed and varies with each row

Comment: I'm not able to execute that line the way it is....issues with the second  '+', ';' and the chars. Would it be better if I separately get the condition for each row then execute this procedure with the condition as an input variable?

Comment: See my second edit to the last code, I just overlooked the string concatenation order and made a really silly mistake :P, trivial to fix anyway. You cannot execute that with the condition as an input variable, because the variable contains *code*, not just a value, that's why you absolutely need dynamic SQL. What I did is just compose that string for all rows (note that the first SELECT is all about simple string manipulation) and the run all at once.